# TCL, receive args as an argument and pass it to another procedure

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I tried to do the following in TCL and got the following error
"list must be an even number of elements" because $args is seen as one list when passed to B.

Is there a clever way of passing $args to B?

```
proc A {a args} {        
    #call B and pass it args
    B 2 $args
}

proc B {b args} {
    set options(-flag1)  0
    set options(-option) serial

    array set options $args
    #use options
}
```

Comment: Are you using `array set` command? Share the full code.

Comment: There you go @Dinesh I have updated the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
B 2 {*}$args
```

If we simplify the procedures a bit:

```
proc A args {
    puts [info level 0]
    B $args
}
proc B args {
    puts [info level 0]
}
```

If we call `A` with some values, `B` will receive those values packaged in a list. This list, being a single item in `args`, is not fit to pass to `array set`, since that command needs an even-sized list.

```
% A a b c d
A a b c d
B {a b c d}
```

Change the invocation of `B` to this:

```
proc A args {
    puts [info level 0]
    B {*}$args
}
```

Now, if we call `A`, each argument to `A` will become a distinct argument to `B`, and `$args` can now be used as an argument to `array set`.

```
% A a b c d
A a b c d
B a b c d
```

As nurdglaw points out, Tcl 8.4 or older does not have the `{*}` syntax, which means `eval` must be used to invoke `B`. One way to do it is

```
eval [linsert $args 0 B]
```

but one could also use the slightly less secure (it can lead to loss of argument structure)

```
eval B $args
```

Tcl 8.4 isn't supported any more, and there is every reason to upgrade to 8.5 or 8.6.

Documentation: [eval](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/eval.htm), [info](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/info.htm), [linsert](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/linsert.htm), [proc](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/proc.htm), [puts](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/puts.htm), [{*}](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/Tcl.htm)

Comment: Just to dot the last i... The `{*}` operator was introduced in Tcl 8.5. If you *really must* use an earlier version you need to call B via the rather more opaque `eval [linsert $args 0 B]` - which creates a new list comprising B and all the individual arguments and then evaluates that list as a command.

Comment: Given that it's `args` which is guaranteed to be a proper list, you'd be OK with `eval [list B] $args`. It's more comprehensible than the `linsert` version. But ___definitely upgrade___ since 8.4 isn't supported at all any more.

Comment: Dammmn!! peter and @nurdglaw, I can't thank you enough. Saved my day. And about the version, I am using 8.3. I am just starting to work for a big company and I don't own the code. I don't think they will want to upgrade any time soon. But I will ask.